# Submenu blue color hover in bootstrap

Tags: joomla, twitter-bootstrap, joomla3.0

I have a site running joomla 3.0, and I'm trying to customize the menu bar.
The template is protostar and Im using the nav-pills style to make the menu bar run horizontal on the top.

The problem that I have is that I cannot find where I need to change or include css to CHANGE the rollover BLUE color on the submenu.

Also I would like to know how to change the color on that white little arrow on the submenu.

[Image of the menu I want to edit](http://revista-amauta.org/wp-content/uploads/2013/02/rolloverpills.png)

Comment: can you provide a link to your site so the element can be inspected or download Firebug (for Firefox) or use Chrome Dev Tools to inspect the element yourself.

Answer (score 1):

The overall tip worked for me as well. Joomla 3.x must use the .navigation .nav-child:hover section as above. 
I also had to change the gradient lines section as one of them was being invoked.
Just changing the background lines did not show up.
I though about deleting them but instead made the start/stop the same.
Guessing that what gets used is a browser based choice if an option fits.

Answer (score 0):

Just went on the Bootstrap site and inspected the element and it appears to be on lines 2927 to 2934 of bootstrap.css:

```
.dropdown-menu li > a:hover,
.dropdown-menu li > a:focus,
.dropdown-submenu:hover > a {
  color: #ffffff;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: #0081c2;
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #0088cc, #0077b3);
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 0 100%, from(#0088cc), to(#0077b3));
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #0088cc, #0077b3);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #0088cc, #0077b3);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #0088cc, #0077b3);
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#ff0088cc', endColorstr='#ff0077b3', GradientType=0);
}
```

`background-color: #0081c2;` is for non CSS3 compatible browsers and everything below is for CSS3 compatible.

Do bare in mind that Joomla may have changed things around in the **bootstrap.css** file so it may be on a different line, however you can simply search for the following:

```
.dropdown-submenu:hover > a
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Thankx for the Help Lodder! Saddly it did not worked. I found that I had to change not the `.dropdown-submenu:hover > a {` but instead `.navigation .nav-child:hover > a {`
Still thankx for taking to time on trying to help me!

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem. You can use this selector:

```
.navigation .nav-child li a:hover{
```

The KEY THING though is to set

```
background-image:none;
```

as the default style uses a gradient, not just a background colour!